# PostgreSQL: Create a new column based on another column and a list

Tags: arrays, string, postgresql, list

Table1

| Animal | Habitat |
| --- | --- |
| Lion | Zoo, Forest, Home, Sea |
| Fish | Sea, Zoo, Aquarium |
| Dog | Home, Zoo, Wild |
| Bird | Sea, Forest, Home |

I want another column that has values from the list

list1 = [Zoo, Home]

Expected Output

| Animal | Habitat |
| --- | --- |
| Lion | Zoo, Home |
| Fish | Zoo |
| Dog | Home |
| Bird | Home |

Comment: Change your datamodel to 3NF: A table with the animals, another table with the habitats and the most important table, the one that connects animals and habitats. Multiple values in a single field are a recipe for problems in a relational database.

Comment: It is unclear why you want "another column"

Comment: @Luuk For each row, I want only the values contained in list1, hence the new column.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thanks for the advice. This is the data I have, and that's the output required. I will consider 3NF if that helps. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `table1` is defined like this:

```
create table table1 as 
select animal, habitat from (values 
 ('Lion',Array ['Zoo','Forest','Home','Sea']),
 ('Fish',Array['Sea', 'Zoo', 'Aquarium']),
 ('Dog',Array['Home', 'Zoo', 'Wild']),
 ('Bird',Array['Sea', 'Forest', 'Home'])) as a(animal, habitat)
```

intersection of arrays can be done like this

```
select animal,array_agg(one_habitat) from (
  select animal, unnest(habitat) one_habitat from table1
) a 
where one_habitat = ANY(Array['Zoo','Home'])
group  by animal
```

| animal | array_agg |
| --- | --- |
| Lion | Home,Zoo |
| Fish | Zoo |
| Dog | Home,Zoo |
| Bird | Home |

Assuming, that habitat column is not real array

```
create table table2 as 
select animal, habitat from (values 
 ('Lion','Zoo, Forest, Home, Sea'),
 ('Fish','Sea, Zoo, Aquarium'),
 ('Dog','Home, Zoo, Wild'),
 ('Bird','Sea, Forest, Home')) as a(animal, habitat)
```

Query

```
select animal,string_agg(one_habitat,', ') from (
  select animal, unnest(string_to_array(habitat,', ')) one_habitat from table2
) a 
where one_habitat = ANY(Array['Zoo','Home'])
group  by animal
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2d8b3e39be5a2a8e663b0dd0e33e1595)

Answer (score 0):

First get the database normalized, and then use string_agg() for the result:

```
select Animal,string_agg(Habitat,',') as Habitat
from (
   select animal, trim(unnest( string_to_array(Habitat,','))) as Habitat 
   from table1
) x
where Habitat in (select trim(unnest( string_to_array('Zoo,Home',','))))
group by Animal;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=437118745dd70ec8443c1d1eb4b8cea6)